# Creating Weka classifier model without evaluation

Tags: java, model, classification, weka, training-data

I am trying to use java to feed a training dataset to Weka and get the model as output.

Found [this](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Saving+and+loading+models) instruction in Weka wiki:

You save a trained classifier with the -d option (dumping), e.g.:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t /some/where/train.arff -d /other/place/j48.model
```

The problem is when I use the mentioned command it first builds the model (takes seconds) and then it evaluates the data using 10-fold cross validation method, which takes minutes and is not needed.

The question is how can use weka to model the data for me without evaluating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -no-cv -t /some/where/train.arff -d /other/place/j48.model
```

How I got there:

```
java weka.classifiers.trees.J48 --help
```

lists the available options, among others:

```
-no-cv        Do not perform any cross validation.
```

So when I use your command and add the `-no-cv` flag, that seems to do what you want.

Comment: How about for doing this in Java (the library) rather than the CLI pre-packaged app?

Comment: @Hack-R I was doing this as part of a research, the application was just for demonstration. I was using C# at the time that's why it seemed easier just to use CLI.